# Progress Animation using JS

Tags: css, css-animations, angular-animations

I came through this kind of animation while working on Asana, I am trying to implement it in my Angular 6 project, but still don't have an idea, how can I proceed in implementing this kind of animation?

Initially, step is to fill the div with different colors as shown in gif.
This is what I have tried till so far.

```
@Component({
  selector: '',
  templateUrl: '',
  styleUrls: [''],
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(700, style({ opacity: 1, background: ' linear-gradient(to bottom left, rgb(123, 98, 221), rgb(37, 77, 180))' }))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate(1000, style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})


  <div class="" [@fadeInOut] *ngIf = 'showFeedback'>
    <p>Create</p>
  </div>
```

Currently this is how it looks for me.

[image]

This is what I want to achieve.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ksav added what I have tried till so far.

Comment: Please share a [minimal, concrete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead. What you've shared doesn't really give us a full picture of your implementation.

Comment: @Terry I have updated the .html code for the same, and added the gif of how it looks for me right now, let me know what else do you think is needed to be added.

Comment: @Terry it's solved now, But still there are downvotes in the Question I don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

I myself solved the problem.
Here is the sandbox for the same.

https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-c4kth

And here is how it looks.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Make a normal progress bar and use a gif image as `background-image`, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u2wvxo5c/14/

Comment: This is a kind if an hack, I am trying to implement the same using JS.

Comment: You can use tool like this https://www.gradient-animator.com/ control the time and behavior with angular animations, But I suggest you to use a gif for performance, But if you want to change the color as the progress good luck with angular-animations it's better for this case.

Comment: I solved it and added the solution as an answer here.